# Workaround for RecyclerView height measurement with horizontal LinearLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

#### Problem

I want to have a RecyclerView with **width=match_parent** and **height=wrap_content**. I need to display items horizontally so I use a proper LinearLayoutManager.

I face a problem with a RecyclerView behaviour. The items of my list have different content (some values are present, other are absent in different items), thus the height of my items can vary. 
And when I scroll the list and further items have bigger content than first items, the height of a RecyclerView doesn't adjust to display its children properly, but it cuts their content. 
**It could work only if the first item is the biggest one.**

#### Research

I saw some old question from 2016 when people had some similar issues. Most of the solutions recommend to update the recyclerView version to *'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'*. 
But nowadays we use Androidx. The current stable version for recyclerView is *1.0.0* I tried *1.1.0-rc1* but got the same result.

Also, I tried to **setAutoMeasureEnabled(true)** for my LinearLayoutManager, but it doesn't work as well.

#### My Workaround

So finally I tried to update the ViewHolder view not directly by assigning values to TextViews, but through view.post(Runnable {}). And it works, I don't know exactly why.

[Not working example GIF](https://gifyu.com/image/k1EF)

[Working example GIF - with a help of view.post(Runnable {})](https://gifyu.com/image/k1Ef)

The expected behaviour is shown on a second GIF: as soon as we scroll to the item with a bigger content, the view size gets updated and recyclerView height gets updated as well.

#### My Question

Do you think the above workaround is okay? Maybe you have some more intelligent ideas / approaches?
Thank you for help and attention.

**main_activity.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#C5C510" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        tools:text="dsgsdfgsdf"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTextView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        tools:text="dsgsdfgsdf"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTextView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        tools:text="dsgsdfgsdf"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        recyclerView.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = Adapter(100) // 100 is the number of items to be displayed, adapter generates them
    }
}
```

**Adapter snippet (Default, Doesn't work as expected):**

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, pos: Int) {
        holder.itemView.itemTextView1.text = "String  \n" + pos.toString()
        holder.itemView.itemTextView2.text = "String  \n" + pos.toString()
        holder.itemView.itemTextView3.text = "String  \n" + pos.toString()

        holder.itemView.itemTextView2.visibility = if (pos > 10) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        holder.itemView.itemTextView3.visibility = if (pos > 30) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
```

**Adapter snippet (Makes the RecyclerView work as expected):**

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, pos: Int) {
        holder.itemView.post {
            holder.itemView.itemTextView1.text = "String  \n" + pos.toString()
            holder.itemView.itemTextView2.text = "String  \n" + pos.toString()
            holder.itemView.itemTextView3.text = "String  \n" + pos.toString()

            holder.itemView.itemTextView2.visibility = if (pos > 10) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            holder.itemView.itemTextView3.visibility = if (pos > 30) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE

        }
    }
```

Comment: Generally you should avoid changing size/layout of your `ViewHolder`s inside `onBindViewHolder`. I suggest creating 3 different item types and moving your visibility calls into `onCreateViewHolder`.

Comment: @Pawel Interesting idea, I will try it. One concern I have about this approach is that the described view is just an example, in my real task I have more complex view with different labels which can be VISIBLE or GONE so they impact the view height.   So this approach assumes I will need a big set of different view types (for every possible combination of my fields). 

Anyway, I didn't hear before about avoiding changing size/layout inside onBindViewHolder. Could you, please, provide some links to get more info?

Thank you :)